# Scrapy and Start URLs

Tags: scrapy

I'm scraping the text from the title tags off of a bunch of pages but also want to include my start URL as a field in my item. Does anyone know how I could do that? When I export the data to a CSV I want to see the start URL next to the title I'm pulling.

Here's the code for my spider---

```
class QuadNumbers(BaseSpider):
    name = "quad_numbers"
    allowed_domains = ["quadratec.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/abc",
                  "http://www.example.com/abc",]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//title')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            item = QuadNumbersItem()
            item['title'] = site.xpath('text()').extract()
            item['start_url'] = __________??
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
item['start_url'] = response.url
```